# Possible cause of the one time login link sent via e-mail to be broken?

Tags: users, emails, navigation, tokens

edit: it appears to be a bug, reported here https://www.drupal.org/node/2329723

---

When I, as the Admin, add a new user and let Drupal notify him via mail, the one-time login link is broken:

```
http://www.exmaple.com///www.exmaple.com/user/reset/...
```

Any idea why Drupal would create such a link? There is no module which alters this mail or tokens.

Comment: Where is Drupal installed, locally? Virtual hosts? Anythin with Apache conf that may meddle with this? Htaccess?

Comment: all other links look fine, its a live server. standard htaccess, standard apache conf (like our other websites have)

Answer (score 2):

There must be **something**, Drupal does not create broken links by default. Sadly, we can't debug your site for you. literally are not able to. See [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_mail_tokens/7) - URL is accessible as `[user:one-time-login-url]` token, so if nothing overrides default support for this token, it must be OK.

Inspect http://example.com/admin/config/people/account, Password recovery tab. By default it should look like this:

> [user:name],
>
> A request to reset the password for your account has been made at [site:name].
>
> You may now log in by clicking this link or copying and pasting it to your browser:
>
> [user:one-time-login-url]
>
> This link can only be used once to log in and will lead you to a page where you can set your password. It expires after one day and nothing will happen if it's not used.
>
> --  [site:name] team

If this token is alone in it's line, just like above, then you know something interferes with tokens. If it's not, then maybe some automatic HTML syntax correction kicked in, and messed up your layout? It is impossible to tell without actually debugging your site.

Comment: i know that you cant debug my site :) i checked the mail text, its original, still so something is altering the token. i guess i will have to disable module by module, test and error.. :)

Comment: @Alex Good luck. I'd really like to be able to tell you more, but sadly I'm not.

Comment: it is pathologic O.o now thats weird!

Comment: @Alex weird indeed. Glad you figured it out but... sorry, have no idea what to do next.

Comment: thats okay, i reported a bug https://www.drupal.org/node/2329723

Answer (score 2):

Its a long time since this question has been posed; but I faced the same problem yesterday, and searched for a solution on the net.  There are a lot of technical details floating about, and the original poster has referenced the issue on the drupal.org site; though the remedies pertain to Drupal 6.

The solution for Drupal 7 is as follows:

goto administration >> configuration >> content authoring >> text formats

In 'text formats' there are editable options for 'full html', 'plain text', and 'filtered html'.  Clicking on each, at the bottom, there's the sub-section 'Filter Settings' and over here you can change the 'Maximum link text length' from its default value of 72 char to anything you fancy 147, 255, 257, etc.

On my site, this resulted in a successful use of the one-time login link which was full and unbroken.